# Testing with Stripe's test account with real(live) created stripe tokens

Tags: stripe-payments

I have to use a live database to test stripe payments using customer stripe tokens that are already stored in the database. This are real customer stripe tokens based on real credit cards. But I am using the test account credentials to make payments to. I don't want to make real payments to the stripe account.
My question is can I  and how can I use this live tokens to make test payments to my test account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use live resources in test mode or vice-versa. The "test" and "live" parts of your Stripe accounts are two different environments that cannot communicate with each other.

You'd need to [create customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) in test mode, using the [testing card numbers](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards) that Stripe provides, in order to use them in test payments.

Comment: that's what i was worried about. Thanks for the answer.  I will maybe create test account's i can use for stripe testing.

Comment: When testing locally on a dev machine using a backup of live data, is possible to differenciate *live* Connected Accounts and *test* ones ?